# FIrebase Database addListenerForSingleValueEvent listner never called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I have a chat scree which having Firebase database support for chat message. I can post message to  screen and also to database, but the issue comes when I leave the chat and come back to chat screen.

The Chat screen becomes empty and I want to load all previous chat from Firebase database. So I created one more Firebase reference with chat node, but unable to get users chat because `onDataChange` in onCreate is never called.

Here is my chat screen class

```
public class Chat_Screen extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,ChildEventListener{

    public static final String TAG = "###CHAT SCREEN###";
    private EditText TypedMsg;
    private ImageButton SendButton,Emo_Button;
    String UserName_Intent,UserImage_Intent,UserID_Intent,Room_Name_Intent;
    String Chat_Msg,Chat_UserName;

    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    Iterator iterator;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    List<Chat_Wrapper> message=new ArrayList<>();;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_screen_main);
        TypedMsg= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Text_Message);
        SendButton= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Send);
        Emo_Button= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Smiley);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Toolbar);
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("This Is Chat Room");
        progressDialog.show();

        // GET INTENT VALUES FROM USER PROFILE CLASS

        UserName_Intent=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Get_Name");
        UserImage_Intent=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Get_Image");
        UserID_Intent=getIntent().getExtras().getString("Get_Phone");
        Room_Name_Intent=getIntent().getExtras().getString("room_user");

        // RECYCLER VIEW
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Chat_Screen_Message_List);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        //FIREBASE FETCH ALL PREVIOUS CHAT OF USERS/CHATROOM ------THIS NEVER CALLS
        DatabaseReference db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Room_Name_Intent);
        Log.d(TAG,"Database Reference of child "+db);
        db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG,"Value of SnapShop is calling");
                    Log.d(TAG,"Value of SnapShop is calling "+snapshot.getValue());
                    Log.d(TAG,"Value of SnapShop is calling 2nd "+snapshot.getValue());

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        Log.d(TAG,"Value of List "+message+" Value of Adapter "+adapter);
        adapter=new Chat_Adapter(this,message);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);



        //INITIALIZING MESSAGE ARRAYLIST


        SendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().getRoot().child(Room_Name_Intent);
        databaseReference.addChildEventListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_screen_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //HANDLE ITEM SELECTION
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.sendFile:
                Log.d(TAG, "Send File Menu Clicked");
                return true;
            case R.id.geo:
                Log.d(TAG, "Geo Fencing Button Clicked");
                return true;
            case R.id.Call:
                Log.d(TAG, "Call Button Clicked");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Call Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int itemClick=v.getId();

        switch (itemClick){
            case R.id.Chat_Screen_Send:
                Log.d(TAG,"Send Button Pressed");

                Log.d(TAG,"FireBase Chat Room Level "+databaseReference);
                //GET MESSAGE FROM EDIT TEXT INTO HASHMAP TO UPDATE DATABASE
                Map<String,Object> map=new HashMap<>();
                map.put("Name",UserName_Intent);
                map.put("Message",TypedMsg.getText().toString());

                String Temp_Key=databaseReference.push().getKey();
                Map<String,Object> RoomKey=new HashMap<>();
                databaseReference.updateChildren(RoomKey);
                DatabaseReference message_Root=databaseReference.child(Temp_Key);
                message_Root.updateChildren(map);
                Log.d(TAG,"Msg Root "+message_Root);

                TypedMsg.setText("");
                break;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        iterator=dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){

            Chat_Msg=(String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue();
            Chat_UserName= (String) ((DataSnapshot)iterator.next()).getValue();

            Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
            int hour=calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int min=calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int second=calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            Log.d(TAG,"Time of the Day "+hour+" -- "+min+" -- "+second);
            String time=(hour+" -- "+min+" -- "+second);





            Log.d(TAG,Chat_Msg+" TIME "+time+" PHONE "+UserID_Intent+" User Image "+UserImage_Intent+" User Name "+UserName_Intent);

            Chat_Wrapper chat_wrapper=new Chat_Wrapper(Chat_Msg,time,UserID_Intent,UserImage_Intent);
            message.add(chat_wrapper);

            adapter.notifyItemInserted(adapter.getItemCount()+1);


            Log.d(TAG,"Chat Msg & User Name "+Chat_Msg+" "+Chat_UserName+" Message List "+message.size());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the structure of your chat and where you creating room(Nodes)?

Answer (score 1):

Get the whole structure with

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

then get the child you want with `mDatabase.child("yourChildId")`. This returns a reference to you. Set an `.addListenerForSingleValueEvent` to that reference. Did you try something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This might be cause every time you enter in child you calling `firebase.updateChildren` it will delete all previous data and create fresh node your code is fine it will fetch all data. Just make sure you don't create fresh room each time you enter in room